# Count the results from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Count the results returned from a stored procedure.

### The problem

I have the following code on my `ProductsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DailyOffers()
{
    var productsList = Products.BuildOffersList();
    ViewBag.Title = String.Format("Ofertas de hoje ({0:dd/MM/yyyy})", 
                                                   DateTime.Now);
    ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = ??;
    ViewBag.CurrentCategory = "Daily-Offers";
    return View(productsList);
}
```

As you can see, there is a builder on this method. This builder returns the Stored Procedure result. And I want to count the number of results that this procedure returns.

### What I'm thinking about

Maybe this?:

```
ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = productsList.Count;
```

### Technical details

I'm using C#.NET + MySql + Entity Framework 5 + Razor Engine.

Comment: what's wrong with what you've suggested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Products.BuildOffersList();` does in fact return a List (and not an IEnumerable/IQueryable) then what you've suggested should be fine and won't result in multiple enumerations.

```
 ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = productsList.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Use parameter "output" on Stored Procedure and create parameter "out" on your method.

```
@ROWCOUNT INT OUTPUT

SELECT
FROM
WHERE

SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
```